# How can optimize images created in real time?

Tags: php, image, image-compression

How can optimize images created in real time? I have a php file that creates chess diagrams with FEN in real time. I use ~12 of those chess diagrams on my main web page at http://communitychessclub.com/index.php

Is there a way I could pipe or tee the img url?

Comment: what about using /images/table/2kr1b1r1p3pppp3pn25q2Q2P42N4PPP3PP1R1B2RK1.png, images should be cached, not created every time it is called. So create image once on first request, save it, and show it from disk cache next time it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these image don't change on every request, so you should definitely cache them. 
Make hash (sha1, md5) string from attributes for file name and save them as jpegs. On every page request check if file exist, if not, generate, cache and return it. It will be way faster.

To optimize more you could use ajax. Return page with placeholders for images, then load each image with ajax and replace placeholders.

Comment: How do I use ajax to do that?

Comment: One way of doing that would be to add placeholder img tags like 

`<img class="placeholder" src="/placeholder.png" data-img="/gen_img.php?src=param1">`

and replace via ajax after page have loaded.
`$('.placeholder').each(function(){
 
 var image = $(this);
 var url = image.attr('data-img');
 
 $.get(url, function(return){
  image.attr('src', return);
 })
});`